# Existence of a certain nonzero vector in $\mathbb F_p ^{2p-1}$ with vanishing inner products with two given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Suppose we have two arbitrary vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $\mathbb F_p ^{2p-1}$ ($p$ is an odd prime number, and $\mathbb F_p$ is the finite field with $p$ elements):

> Now is there any nonzero vector $w$ **contains only $0$ and $1$** s.t the inner product of $v_1.w=v_2.w=0$?

For example if $v_1=\underbrace{(2,0,2,0\cdots,2)}_{2p-1}$ and $v_2=\underbrace{(0,1,0,1\cdots,0)}_{2p-1}$ then we can put $w=v_1=\underbrace{(1,0,1,0\cdots,1)}_{2p-1}$ and then $v_1.w=2p=0$ in $\mathbb F_p$ and $v_2.w=0$.

It's easy to see that when $v_1$ and $v_2$ consist of only $0$ and $1$, then always there exists such a $w$, but in the general case, I have been trying some tricks from linear algebra and combinatorics without any success!

And I should say that in $\mathbb F_p ^{2p-2}$ there is a counterexample:
$v_1=\underbrace{(1,0,1,0\cdots,0)}_{2p-2}$, $v_2=\underbrace{(0,1,0,1\cdots,1)}_{2p-2}$

Comment: If $v_1,v_2$ are linearly dependent, then it should be easy to find such a $w$. Thus the question is equivalent to asking:

Let $U \leq \mathbb{F}_p^{2p-1}$ be a subspace of dimension $2p-3$. Is it then true that $U$ always contains a nonzero vector containing only zero and one?
Such a space $U$ has a unique representation through a reduced row echelon from of a basis matrix and we can assume w.l.o.g. that all pivots are up front, such that we have two columns to work with in the end. I get stuck at finding a general way to prove it from here, but maybe that approach might help you. :)

Comment: @Bemte I did some works like this but...!

Comment: @Bemte And if you think deeper your argument tends to nothing just the original question(:

Comment: A cool question! No light bulbs, I'm afraid. Translated it to the form: given $2p-1$ vectors in $\Bbb{F}_p^2$ then a non-empty subset of them adds up to $(0,0)$. But that didn't help :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** It can be proved by use of [Chevalley–Warning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem) and $p-1$th power in $2p-1$ variable, to get only $0$ and $1$.